# Add pause on hover to jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Can someone assist me in trying to get pause on hover working with this example.  Essentially I need it to do the following.

- Pause interval On Hover
- Highlight item hovered over
- on hover out resume rotate

Code ([fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Wja4r/13/)):

```
var $f = $('ul').find('.frame');
function recursive(i) {
    $f.removeClass('showing').eq(i).addClass('showing');
    setTimeout(function () {
        recursive(++i % $f.length)
    }, 1000);
}
recursive(0);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Working DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Wja4r/16/)

You might need to tweak this a bit to fit into your requirements. Basically the idea is to clear interval on mouse over and resume recursion on mouseout & keep a reference to count.

```
var $f = $('ul').find('.frame'),
    timeOut, 
    count; 

function recursive(i) {
    count = i;
    $f.removeClass('showing').eq(i).addClass('showing');
    timeOut = setTimeout(function () {
        recursive(++i % $f.length)
    }, 1000);
}

$('ul li').hover(function(){
    clearTimeout(timeOut);
});

$('ul li').mouseout(function(){
    recursive(count);
});


recursive(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this

```
$(".frame").hover(function () {
    clearTimeout(t);
    console.log(this);
    $(this).addClass("showing");
}, function () {
    recursive(0);
});
```

[***Fiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/Wja4r/21/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var $f = $('ul').find('.frame');
$('ul li').hover(function(){
    $f.removeClass('showing');
    $(this).addClass('showing');
    clearTimeout(timer);
}, function(){
    recursive($(this).index());
});

function recursive(i) {
    $f.removeClass('showing').eq(i).addClass('showing');
    timer = setTimeout(function () {
        recursive(++i % $f.length)
    }, 1000);
}

recursive(0);
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Wja4r/22/)